# Testing afterInsert in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

Simply, I have the following scenario:

```
class OwnedRights {
    static belongsTo = [comp: Competition]

    @Transactional
    def afterInsert() {
        // Erroring out here.
        Event.findAllByComp(comp).each { event -> 
            // Do something with event.
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to save in my unit test with something like the following:

```
def ownedRights = new OwnedRights(params).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

I am seeing the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:85)
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:194)

This lead to me to [this Jira Issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11045) which indicated that I was not using the `@Mock` annotation, however in my test, I am mocking all used domain classes:

```
@Mock([OwnedRights, Sport, Competition, Event])
```

Is this a known problem with hibernate events containing GORM logic?

**Attempts to Solve**

I have attempted to override the `afterInsert()` and `beforeDelete` methods by using the metaClass:

```
OwnedRights.metaClass.afterInsert = null;
OwnedRights.metaClass.beforeDelete = null;
```

and

```
OwnedRights.metaClass.afterInsert = {};
OwnedRights.metaClass.beforeDelete = {};
```

Both of which had no effect on the outcome. If I comment out the afterInsert event, the save works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning @Mock. This can only be used in unit tests, but then you should never try to test transactions in unit tests.

That's a no-no. Test transactions in an integration test. The work they did in allowing you to have an in-memory GORM implementation is wonderful, but transactions are a database feature. You just can't expect an in-memory implementation (backed by a Map!!) to behave like a database. What you are testing is the behavior of the GORM implementation for unit tests, not your actual database. So the test is useless in the real world.

Comment: I removed the @Transactional annotation. In the end, I just removed the events altogether and did a little refactoring.

Comment: So, no more afterInsert ?... Bummer. I'm trying to test code in an afterInsert and can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I used this annotation (in unit test file) to solve the problem.

```
@TestFor(FooBarService)
```

And yes, it's possible to test Service layer using unit tests (but some of GORM methods may not be available, depending of your Grails version)